# Is there any API service that converts a CSV file (inside url) to a simple table on a webpage so I can call an API to take a screenshot of this page?

Tags: api, screenshot, csv, table

The project will be running automatically in `Google App Script`, which is based on `Javascript`..

I have a `URL` that when I open, downloads a `CSV` file to my computer.

But instead of downloading it to my computer, I would like a service where I would put the `URL` and it would convert this file to a page with the online table.

Because from this online table I'm going to use an API (https://screenshotlayer.com/documentation) to take a screenshot of the web page and save on my `Google Drive`.

Does this service exist?

Note: The option to use `Google App Script` to convert the `CSV` into a table and publish this table as a page does not solve my problem, because the page created i need to scroll the screen manually for the new data to appear, so when the `API` takes the screenshot , only a part of the table appears.

Comment: For what you are specifically asking, I can't think of any other option other than opening Excel and exporting as an image.

However, alternatively a [command line](https://github.com/wfxr/csview) tool that renders the output to the console might be helpful in automating an output.

Comment: Hello friend @Lockszmith , unfortunately this option would not help me but thanks a lot for the tip, it may help other people who see this question in the future!

Comment: would using something like [OnlyOffice](https://www.onlyoffice.com/) work?
It's a self-hosted web based office-suite. You will still need to figure out how to feed the URL into it, but it will open in the Web Browser. I use with a self-hosted [NextCloud](https://nextcloud.com/) instance, but this might be an overkill solution for what you are seeking.

Comment: Hi @Lockszmith I think this option will end up falling into the same current problem, because when taking a screenshot of the page, if it is dynamic and you need to scroll the page manually to show all the data, the full screenshot becomes impossible.

It needs to be a page that loads in its entirety regardless of size, without a scroll bar inside the other as we see on spreadsheet platforms.

Google spreadsheets have this problem too.

Comment: Makes sense, my last suggestion - I'll stop bothering you after this :) - look for a data rendering library, one that can get CSV and render an SVG (or PNG) file for you.
I bet these are not only for graphs, but you may be able to render tabular information as well.